# Django: How can I use a variable inside an if statement in the template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

My views.py hands over a variable called "preSelect" that contains a Integer value.

Inside the template I want to use that Integer in an If statement to check if the current for loop counter is less equal or greater than than my value.

```
{% if forloop.counter <= {{ preSelect }} %}
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checks" id="1" value={{ row.0 }} checked/></td>
{% else %}
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="checks" id="1" value={{ row.0 }} /></td>
{% endif %}
```

This however returns me the following error:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: POST Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>
> Django Version: 1.10.2 Python Version: 2.7.11 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'testsetcreation'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Template error: In template
>   D:\Django\testsetcreation\templates\testsetcreation\testsetView.html,
>   error at line 61    Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'   51
>   :                     Comment    52 :
>   SW Version    53 :                     HW Version
>   54 :                     ABP    55 :
>   Project    56 :                     57 :
>       58 :                 59 :             {% for row in
>   rows %}    60 :                     61 :                      {%
>   if forloop.counter <= {{ preSelect }} %}     62 :
>       63 :                     {% else %}    64 :
>       65 :                     {% endif %}    66 :
>   {{ row.1 }}    67 :                     {{ row.2 }} 
>   68 :                         69 :
>       70 :                         {{
>   row.3 }}    71 :
>
> Traceback:
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "D:\Django\testsetcreation\views.py" in testsetView
>     102.     return render(request, 'testsetcreation/testsetView.html', context)
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
>     30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in
>   render_to_string
>     67.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in
>   get_template
>     21.             return engine.get_template(template_name)
>
> File
>   "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in
>   get_template
>     39.             return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in
>   get_template
>     160.         template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in
>   find_template
>     134.                         name, template_dirs=dirs, skip=skip,
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py"
>   in get_template
>     44.                     contents, origin, origin.template_name, self.engine,
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   **init**
>     191.         self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   compile_nodelist
>     233.             return parser.parse()
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in parse
>     518.                     raise self.error(token, e)
>
> Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at / Exception Value: Could not
>   parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'

Answer (score 5):

in Jinja, when you use the {%%} marks, don't put the variables inside {{}}

#### Example Code

```
{% if x > y %}
    # Do something
{% endif %}
```

So the code in your case would be

```
{% if forloop.counter <= preSelect %}
    # Do Something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It applies to the default template engine, not only Jinja

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, in the default Django template engine it is not necessary to wrap the template variables in curly braces when they are used inside the conditional statement. So simply remove the braces:

```
{% if forloop.counter <=  preSelect  %}
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checks" id="1" value={{ row.0 }} checked/></td>
{% else %}
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="checks" id="1" value={{ row.0 }} /></td>
{% endif %}
```